# Mysql Query to Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, view, mysql-8.0

i have got access to a view of a datatable (mysql 8) which has the following values:

[Values DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EX9H8.png)

now I tried to write an mysql query to fill up the Null values with the last value, because our visualisation tool cannot use null values and the lines in the graph will disappear.

```
SELECT UTCTIME,
case when Flammtemperatur1 is NULL then
@vorheriger_wert_Flammtemperatur1
else
@vorheriger_wert_Flammtemperatur1 := Flammtemperatur1
end as Flammtemperatur_1,
case when Flammtemperatur2 is NULL then
@vorheriger_wert_Flammtemperatur2
else
@vorheriger_wert_Flammtemperatur2 := Flammtemperatur2
end as Flammtemperatur_2,
case when Rauchgasventilator is NULL then
@vorheriger_wert_Rauchgasventilator
else
@vorheriger_wert_Rauchgasventilator := Rauchgasventilator
end as Rauchgasventilator_,
case when Rezirkulation is NULL then
@vorheriger_wert_Rezirkulation
else
@vorheriger_wert_Rezirkulation := Rezirkulation
end as FRezirkulation_
FROM pivot_test
order by utctime asc
```

That works fine, but i need to save this in a view or stored procedure, so that our tool can have access to it. Views are not possible because of the session variables.
Can someone please help me creating a Stored procedure for my problem? I have never written a SP before.

Thanks!

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2xQV.png)

Comment: Add `CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name () ` at the beginning of your query - that's all. Do not forget a space or new line after the parenthesis, replace proc. name with needed one. Then simply execute `CALL procedure_name;`.

Comment: You tag the question as MySQL 8+. If so I'd recommend you to avoid UDVs usage and apply window functions in CTE.

Comment: Thank you a lot - it works.
I use workbench and with new procedure, workbench includes begin and end. If i copy the text in the middle of begin and end, a synthax error appears.
But without it works. :-)

Answer (score 0):

CREATE PROCEDURE XXXXXName @Flammtemperatur1 DECIMAL (3,2), @Flammtemperatur2  DECIMAL (3,2)
, @Rauchgasventilator  DECIMAL (3,2) ,@Rezirkulation  DECIMAL (3,2)
AS
SELECT UTCTIME,
case when Flammtemperatur1 is NULL then
@vorheriger_wert_Flammtemperatur1
else
@vorheriger_wert_Flammtemperatur1 := Flammtemperatur1
end as Flammtemperatur_1,
case when Flammtemperatur2 is NULL then
@vorheriger_wert_Flammtemperatur2
else
@vorheriger_wert_Flammtemperatur2 := Flammtemperatur2
end as Flammtemperatur_2,
case when Rauchgasventilator is NULL then
@vorheriger_wert_Rauchgasventilator
else
@vorheriger_wert_Rauchgasventilator := Rauchgasventilator
end as Rauchgasventilator_,
case when Rezirkulation is NULL then
@vorheriger_wert_Rezirkulation
else
@vorheriger_wert_Rezirkulation := Rezirkulation
end as FRezirkulation_
FROM pivot_test
order by utctime asc